# I want to represent a cyrillic character in some basic way using c++ under windows

Tags: c++, character, encode

So I'm actually trying to make a code that will transform all the cyrillic letters from a word into the relevant latin letter. For example, the russian "я" should become а "q" and so on. So, for now I have found something I think is the best and simplest to understand way to work with cyrillic symbols, which is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *s = "яятя";     //my constant cyrillic char
    char c[10];                 //I'll transform it into that
    CharToOemA(s, c);           //the way I saw on the internet, I have barely understood what it actually does...
    cout << c << endl;          //This gives me the "яяяя" I need, so I'm happy...

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(c); i++)
    {
        //So I'm looping my character and want to somehow compare each single char with some kind of representation of the cyrillic "я"
        //Somehow using the encoding system of the c++ GNU compiler code blocks 13.12
        //Unicode number of "я" - U+044F
        if(c[i] == ...) //What could I use?
        //tried with '\u044F', but it didn't work
            cout << c[i] << " -- this should be a q!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Press any key to continue..." << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I could guess this has been answered a lot of times, but I've currently not found the most right way to work with those damn cyrillic strings and chars in the code itself, to compare them and do stuff with them... So if you could suggest a way to achieve my goal, I'd be thankful...

Comment: `c[i]` is a char, so most probably only 8 bits and can't store values like `'\u044F'`. And calling `strlen(c)` in the for loop again and again is inefficient. Just store it to a variable and check

Comment: Well I've reached the consequence that it's not the right way. :D The problem in this case is that I have no clue how I could basically compare a character that is out of the range of the ANSCII encoding which obviously is the only one that compiler works with ;-; Those d*mn cyrillic symbols... I don't seem to be able to manage them... That little optimisation is clear, I was just typing the code fast to make the example.

Comment: What version of the compiler / of C++ are you working with? And what encoding do you expect your Cyrillic input to be in? UTF-8? UTF-16? Something else?

Comment: C++11 on GNU GCC 2013, I'm not at home now so I'm not really certain with the details, but that's it. UTF-8 is the encoding I need as far as I know, but unicode would be the best option. I'm quite confused and dont't really know what to do about it. If I change work with locale, I can either work with proper cyrillic symbols in the code itself, but it prints some random symbols as an output in the console or I can print them properly but not work with the symbols in the code... It's strange.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not quite sure yet about the required input encoding, a simple way to get started is to assume your input will be in UTF-16.

Since your compiler supports C++11, I believe the following should work for you:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::u16string text = u"яятя";

  for (char16_t c : text)
  {
    if (c == u'я')
      std::cout << 'q';
    else
      std::cout << '?';
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You will notice the following changes to your code:

- I am using Unicode string literals: `яятя` generates a UTF-16 string literal. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for other options
- This implies that each character is two bytes in length, so I am using `std::u16string` to store the string, and the `char16_t` data type to iterate through the characters

If you eventually want to read UTF-8-encoded text from a file etc., you might want to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 after reading the input. The most modern versions of the C++ standard, and the most modern compilers, support conversion functions like this:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> convert;
std::cout << "UTF-8 version: "
          << convert.to_bytes(text)
          << std::endl;
```

And similarly `convert.from_bytes()` for conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16. But your compiler version might not support this correctly yet.

Comment: I didn't get really into the whole theory because I currently have no time, but I wanted to test the code. Well, an error occured.. I don't know if it's due to my olddated software but I guess it's some kind of incompatibility. That's the error: `|5|error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence|` on the lines `std::u16string text = u"яятя";` and `if (c == u'я')` Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've also not found any kind of information about the actual error with that message, pretty much confused and not knowing what to do >.<